# Joomla datepicker storing todays date why is it so?

Tags: joomla, datepicker

When I select the date from calendar Joomla datepicker `JHTML::Calendar()`, it is storing the current (today's) date to the database. What could be the problem? I want to store the value users select from datapicker otherwise default today's date...

Here is my code so far:

```
<td> 
   <?php echo JHTML::calendar(date("d-m-y"),'revdate', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',)); ?> 
</td>
```

Comment: can you show the code you're using for the datepicker, including any html markup too

Comment: <td>
<?php
echo JHTML::calendar(date("d-m-y"),'revdate', 'date', '%Y-%m-%d',array('size'=>'8','maxlength'=>'10','class'=>' validate[\'required\']',));
   ?>
  </td>

Actually i am using mostes tree Joomla component and i am calling Joomla datepicker into that compoenent.